# Valgrind alternative

Tags: macos, valgrind

Since I've installed Xcode 4 (OS X), valgrind stopped working. I get segmentation fault every time I use it. Are there alternatives to Valgrind for debugging and profilling you would recommend?
Please reply if you know it works on Unix, there might be a port for OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind is for memory error checking (mostly anyways, such as leaks and bad access) you might want to use GDB (which comes preinstalled on mac) to check where your segmentation fault is happening. It is built into XCode4 as well.